# Create SQL Server view column using CASE WHEN clause for certain rows

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vewPropertyTransactions] 
AS

SELECT 
      Base.Expense_ID, Base.EstatShareHolder_ID, Base.[Expense Category] AS ExpenseCategory, 

    CASE 
        WHEN 
            Base.EstatShareHolder_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
            Base.DuePayer_ID=Base.PropertyManagementDuePayer_ID AND 
            Base.Payer_ID=Base.EstatShareHolder_ID AND 
            Base.[Expense Category]<>'Maintenace Services'
        THEN Base.[Expense Category]
    END ExpenseCategories

FROM     
    dbo.vewEstatePartnershipTransactionBase AS Base

    ORDER BY Base.Expense_ID

GO
```

It generates a grid view like this:

[image]

Whereas I wish to generate something like this:

[image]

Basically, what I really want to achieve is that when the WHEN clause is not fullfilled then set the value of ExpenseCategories to NULL except for the rows group with the same ExpenseID for which ExpenseCategories should be set to [Expense Category].

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Add an `ELSE` clause that returns the NULL value

Comment: You can nest case statements as well as using ELSE.  You just have to play with the logic until it works for your specific issue.

Comment: You spelled "maintenance" wrong? Looks like it's in the data that way though too.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes; well spotted. Thanks. I will fix it in the database sample.

Comment: You need to look into [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). To give you an actual code answer we will need sample data and table definitions.

Comment: @Alex; Thanks for the suggestion; I have already tried LAG but I couldn't get it to work. It sets ExpenseCategories to the value of [Expense Category] of the previous records that did not fullfill the CASE WHEN conditions.  For example it sets it to RENT for one of the rows with Expense_ID=3752. I will post sample data and table definition.

Comment: Without going back to the original data, and regardless how the first view is created, is it not possible to create the second view from the first one, using CTE or sub-queries or another method? For each group of ExpendID, set all ExpenseCategories entries to the one that has a value, and ignore for other groups. For example, for rows with ExpendID=3749 in table 1 set it to "Property Purchase" and for rows with ExpendID=3752 do nothing.